# 3d touch swift 3 does not open the viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, 3dtouch

I got a 3d touch function in my app delegate for the shortcutitems and it has to instantiate a viewcontroller when 3d touch item clicked from the iphone.

**Here is the code:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if shortcutItem.type == "com.kevinvugts.addStuf" {
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let exerciseVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "exerciseVC") as! exerciseVC
            let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
            root?.present(exerciseVC, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
                    completionHandler(true)
            })
        }
    }
```

This code results in this warning/error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ActiveRest.exerciseVC: 0x131d39320> on <ActiveRest.ViewController: 0x131d0e470> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Has this anything to do with delay?

Thanks for any help!

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`view is not in the window hierarchy` that means your `view of your viewcontroller` is not loaded in memory still. so you are unable to present `viewcontroller` on it. you should have to present viewcontroller from `viewDidAppear` of your `viewcontroller (I mean from your rootviewController)`.

Comment: but this is called in the app delegate sir

Comment: you can't present viewcontroller from `appdelegate` because your `viewHierarchy` is not ready in `appdelegate`!

Comment: i watched this tutorial and did the exact same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO9E5KxixOw

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.kevinvugts.addStuf" {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let exerciseVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "exerciseVC") as! exerciseVC
        window?.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(exerciseVC)

    }
}
```

I made this change and everything works fine.